# Marklogic custom Rest-API endpoint Content-type issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a custom Rest extension and the WS had both GET and POST. What I noticed is that custom rest endpoints does not accept `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Why is that case ? How can I allow my Custom Rest Endpoint to accept `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

And also out-of-box search endpoint `v1/search` does the reverse, it does not accept  `Content-type:multipart/form-data`..

Also another thing I noticed is , in custom rest endpoint when I send `rs:start=1` it treats that as `xs:string`.. but in out-of-box endpoint `start=1` it converts to `xs:unsingedLong`.. I am digging into the actual code for out-of-box and could not find where it does the implicit conversion..

Answer (score 1):

A resource service extension is a server-side plugin for the builtin service that supports predefined HTTP requests and does the housekeeping of mediating the HTTP interaction for you.

If you want a custom endpoint with full control over the HTTP interaction, the best approach is to use a separate application server port for the same content database.

The fact that a value is castable to an integer is not a guarantee that the value should be cast to an integer. The application might expect a string or a double.

In the custom code, it is trivial to case the value to an integer if that's what is expected.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks to Dave, I can set the parameter types.. but my first question is what is reason for  Custom Rest endpoint blocking `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: The comment still thinks of a resource service extension as acustom REST endpoint.  It's not.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the parameter types, when you install a REST extension, you have the option of specifying the type. See [Installing a Resource Service Extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_59112).

Comment: Cool, I don;t know how I missed the specifying the type.. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XQRS](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs). You can create RESTful services accepting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` via [%rest:form-param](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/form-parameters) annotations.

You can perform Content Negotiation, setting constraints for functions using [%rest:consumes / %rest:produces](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/content-negotiation) annotations.

[multipart/form-data](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/form-file-uploads) is supported, including multiple file uploads as well as [multipart/mixed](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/post-put-body#multipart-types) requests which will cast your data into the MarkLogic/XQuery types you want, whether they be JSON, XML, or sem:triple* etc

The framework is smart enough to convert Query Parameters into whatever atomic XDM types you want via [Automatic Type Conversion](http://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/query-parameters).

The library is free, open source and well tested.